# Path Variables in Web Security Expressions and set /users/{userId:\\d+}

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-rest

`spring security 4.1.3.RELEASE` `intercept-url` `request-matcher="mvc"`

I try to use spring-security.xml to config my web security with `request-matche="mvc"`, but the pattern "/users/{userId:id}" dosen't work.

My config just look like the following code:

```
<http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" request-matcher="mvc" 
      access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/{userId:\\d+}" method="GET" access="@webSecurity.isMe(authentication, #userId) or hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/management" method="GET" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"/>
</http>
```

I expecte that the request for /users/12345 will match the pattern /users/{userId:\d+} which will match 12345 to the userId, and the request for /users/management will match the pattern /users/management. However, in fact, the pattern /users/{userId:\d+} dosen't work, it never match the request /users/12345. and if I change the setting to the following code:

```
<http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" request-matcher="mvc" 
      access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/{userId}" method="GET" access="@webSecurity.isMe(authentication, #userId) or hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/management" method="GET" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"/>
</http>
```

Remove the :\d+ from /users/{userId:\d+}, it will match the request for /users/12345. But it will match the request for /users/management as well, which makes the value of userId equals to unexpected "management". I have try ant-matcher and regex-matcher, and I can't find the userId in a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by myself. It's a stupid mistake. To solve the problem, I just need to replace `/users/{userId:\\d+}` with `/users/{userId:\d+}` or `/users/{userId:[0-9]+}` and use AntPathMatcher instead of using MvcPathMatcher. Configuring the security with spring-security.xml is defferent with using javaConfig or using annotation. In javaConfig or annotation @RequestMapping, the content in `""` is String Object, so we need an annother `\` to escape the `\d+`. But in xml, it's unnecessary. If using `\\d+` here, spring security will append it to `\\\\d+`, which will never match number type string. I find this solution when I set a breakpoint in `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.matchStrings(String str, Map<String, String> uriTemplateVariables)` and watch the request.